# Setting up Mysql for Ruby on Rails in Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm on Windows, and I have a working Rails 2.3.8 app on Ruby 1.8.6 with MySQL 5.0 and the mysql gem version 2.8.1. It all works.

I just installed Ruby 1.9.1, installed gems for rails(2.3.8) and mysql. BUT NOW when I run ruby script/server:

**!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.**

I ALREADY INSTALLED IT!

One thing that might be a problem:
When I run "gem list" in my working ruby (v1.8.6) install, it lists "mysql (2.8.1)". BUT when I run "gem list" in the new ruby install (v1.9.1), it lists "mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)". If that's the cause, how do I fix it? If it's not, what on earth is keeping Rails from recognizing the installed mysql gem?

Thanks in advance. I'm sure this is a common upgrade path, so I can't be the only one with this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got some solid info.

Apparently the mysql gem sucks, and shouldn't be relied on going forward.
That's why Rails 3.0.0 officially endorses the [mysql2 gem](http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) instead (`gem install mysql2`), which unfortunately is not supported under Windows yet, though the gem's developer [seems to be working on it](http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/8).

As I try to get my app to Rails 3, I'm just going to make the [easy switch to sqlite3](http://skim.la/2010/08/21/rails-3-rc-on-windows-using-rubyinstaller-192/) until there's a good mysql gem for windows.